Is a subnucleus microscope really possible?
The reason mankind does not now have a sub-picometre microscope is generally attributed to the inability to create a perfect optical system.
The question is, is this true?
Consider a perfect optical system with 1fm / 1am resolution, based on γ-ray. We should expect to observe debris resulting from photofission, not images (like electron microscope) of fine structure.
If we can expect to observe anything interesting other than debris, or if there are better options than γ-ray, please tell me.
Addendum: I think a perfect Photon scanning microscopy would likewise destroy the Atomic nucleus instead of producing a subnucleus image.
If I am wrong, or if physics allows direct subnucleus imaging of the wave function without destroying the Atomic nucleus, please let me know.

The more general term when a high energy photon disrupts a nucleus is photodisintegration https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photodisintegration

The wavefunction cannot be imaged. 2 reasons. 1, it is a model, not reality. 2, it is a feature of the future. We exist in the present, which is the connection between the future and past, which is also where the wavefunction collapses. An image is a representation of a past event. You cannot represent a past event that has not yet happened.

@DavidS I have no interest in talking about the philosophy of physics. As I've already said in the comments section of other replies, I'll accept statistical averaging of observed wave functions without destroying subnucleus. (like Photoionization Microscopy)

Yes, the hard gamma rays will destroy the observed object at once. The other options available (e.g. electrons) bring the same problem.
What's worse, because of the fuzzy geometry of the objects at this scale, you can not really see much more than a statistical image of many, many objecs. You do destroy each one for a single interaction, after all. This is what we get anyway using particle accelerators. So the good optical resolution is of no much use.
Conclusion: use particle accelerators, angle-sensitive detectors and statistics. They tell a lot of interesting stuff.

What happens if you consider neutrinos, axions, or the even more engineering absurdity of WIMPs?

One more question, does physics allow direct subnucleus imaging of the wave function without destroying the Atomic nucleus?

@EmberEdison all those particles have the same exact issues mentioned, strength of interaction doesn't change the problem.

How about evanescent field? Ignoring for why it can be, can an evanescent field excited by a 1pm/100am ray avoid destroying the nucleus?

@EmberEdison One needs some scientific clarity in regard to axions, wimps or whatever the evanescent field is, in order to do some engineering with them. And, as I already mentioned, there are few things to see at the discussed scale.

I guess I have to accept the destruction of the observed object. But if the imaging is faster than the destruction, we should be able to expect to see the correct image?

A particle accelerator is such a microscope. As you say high energy photons have a shorter wavelength, and can therefore resolve finer details. They are also destructive. Other particles are the same.
Particle accelerators slam high energy particles into each other and learn things by watching the pieces that come flying out. Don Lincoln explains this - Particle Detectors Subatomic Bomb Squad
He has more videos that explain how particle accelerators work (and many other physics topics.) Here is a playlist Start looking around video 87.
For a more advanced view of how they work, see this from LibreTexts - Particle Accelerators and Detectors
Or for the details, see this from the CERN Accelerator School - Basic Course on General Accelerator Physics


The reason mankind does not now have a sub-picometre microscope is generally attributed to the inability to create a perfect optical system.

The optical systems stop working much earlier - mostly due to the absence of suitable materials for creating lenses for short wave lengths - the refractive index becomes 1.
Significant progress has been achieved using particles other than photons - notably electrons (scanning electron microscopy, electron microscopy), neutrons, as well as via development of the atomic force microscopy. The "optical" microscopy has been extended in X-ray range - X-ray microscopy.
Some of these methods (AFM, X-ray) are known to achieve subatomic resolutions, but these are apparently more of interest
inn studying macromolecules (proteins, DNA) than single nuclei. The reason is likely that nucleus behaves as a single particle - there just isn't much structure to see. This is also why we talk about splitting a nucleus rather than ionising a nucleus.

(image source)
